# Docker container's networkMode changes to default when running the container

Tags: docker

Docker version - v1.12
OS - Ubuntu 14.04.4-LTS
Clustering mode - Swarm

Created an overlay network:
`$ docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 network create --driver overlay --subnet=10.0.9.0/24 my-net`

Creating the container:
[POST] `http://localhost:2375/container/create?name={id}`

```
{
"Env": [
        "env1=val1"
   ],
   "Cmd": [
       "/Run.sh",
       "launch
    ],
   "Image": "<image>",
   "Volumes": {
       "/tmp" : {}
   },
   "HostConfig": {
     "NetworkMode": "my-net"
   }
}
```

Response of `$docker inspect`:

```
"HostConfig": {
    "Binds": null,
    "ContainerIDFile": "",
    "LogConfig": {
        "Type": "json-file",
        "Config": {}
    },
    "NetworkMode": "my-net",
    "PortBindings": null,
    "RestartPolicy": {
        "Name": "",
        "MaximumRetryCount": 0
    },
    "AutoRemove": false,
    "VolumeDriver": "",
    "VolumesFrom": null,
}
```

This creates container with networkMode as `my-net`. But when I run
the container using the rest API [POST]
`http://localhost:2375/containers/{id}/start` networkMode changes to
`default`.

Response of `$docker inspect`:

```
"HostConfig": {
    "Binds": null,
    "ContainerIDFile": "",
    "LogConfig": {
        "Type": "json-file",
        "Config": {}
    },
    "NetworkMode": "default",
    "PortBindings": null,
    "RestartPolicy": {
        "Name": "",
        "MaximumRetryCount": 0
    },
    "AutoRemove": false,
    "VolumeDriver": "",
    "VolumesFrom": null,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with the docker swarm API change to start the container. This commit tells about the payload structure to be passed. All I needed to change is the payload:

`[POST] http://localhost:2375/containers/{id}/start`

Payload:

```
{
  "NetworkMode": "my-net"
}
```

All docker container hostConfig properties goes in the payload. If left blank then all properties will get reset to default. This API specification should be documented in swarm API docs to avoid confusions.

Answer (score -1):

You should run it with the network flag anyway. look here
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/network-settings

Comment: Issue is not with the cli command. It's when I'm using the rest API.